# Как оптимизировать рекурсию?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, олимпиада

> Поднимаясь по лестнице, заяц прыгает либо на следующую ступеньку, либо через одну, либо через две. Сколькими способами он может поднятся на ступеньку с номером K?

Всё вроде бы понятно...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int vr(int n)
{
  if (n<3) return n;
  else if (n==3) return 4;
  else return vr(n-1)+vr(n-2)+vr(n-3);
}
int main()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  cout << vr(n);
  return 0;
}
```

Но когда программа не прошла тест по времени на 32 ступеньках, до меня наконец дошло, что такой алгоритм порождает немеренное количество повторяемых вычислений, тем самым растрачивая драгоценные ресурсы.
Прошу мудрые головы натолкнуть на мысль истинную, как же сократить количество вычислений заоблачное до количества оптимального.

Comment: Простейший вариант: Создать массив длинной `n` и пройти по нему циклом. Вариант получше: т. к. мы используем только 3 последних элемента, достаточно создать массив всего из трех элементов и проходить по нему несколько раз.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Массив с решениями для n=1,2,3,4?

Comment: Так а откуда взялось упоминание рекурсии? Это требование условия задачи - решить именно рекурсией?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не указывайте в заголовке вопроса ЯП. Он указывается в метках

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну, начать с того, что если вы хотите ограничиться `int`'ами, то в принципе можно оставить рекурсию как есть :) - все равно последнее помещающееся в `int` значение получается для 36.

А вот если взять `unsigned long long`, то, конечно, просто так оставить все нельзя. Конечно, можно отказаться от рекурсии, но мы не ищем легких путей? :)

Так что если вы непременно хотите оставить рекурсию - воспользуйтесь такой разновидностью динамического программирования, как *мемоизация* :)

```
unsigned long long vr(unsigned int n)
{


    // Размера массива 100 хватит за глаза, потому что 
    // последний помещающийся в unsigned long long результат
    // получается при n == 73
    static unsigned long long v[100] = {0};


    if (n<3) return n;
    else if (n==3) return 4;
    else
    {
        if (v[n]) return v[n];
        return v[n] = vr(n-1)+vr(n-2)+vr(n-3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Это ["Числа трибоначчи"](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned K;
  std::cin >> K;

  unsigned long long n = 0;
  for (unsigned long long a = 0, b = 0, c = 1; K > 0; --K, a = b, b = c, c = n)
     n = a + b + c;

  std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

Или просто

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned K;
  std::cin >> K;

  double tribo = 0x1.584c2ef9f4ab1p-2 * std::pow(0x1.d6db7f2d9c5c1p+0, K + 1);
  //                   ^^^ A                            ^^^ B
  // A = 0.336228116994941094225362954014332415157926090020459280443
  // B = 1.839286755214161132551852564653286600424178746097592246778

  std::cout << (unsigned long long) (tribo + 0.5) << std::endl;
}
```

Точные константы в исходной формуле иррациональны. Точности десятичного разложения, приведенного в комментариях, достаточно для вычисления ответа [вплоть до 208 члена последовательности](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec74388d68e11a6c), при условии отсутствия потери точности при выполнении вычислений. При использовании типа `double` (IEEE754 double precision) расхождение возникнет уже на 56 члене последовательности. При использовании типа `long double` (IEEE754 extended precision) расхождение возникнет на 67 члене последовательности.

Comment: Два дополнения... Первое - для условия задачи нужно добавить 1 к аргументу - потому что для ступеньки 1 уже есть один способ на нее забраться (а не 0), и второе - что второй метод начнет врать на 56 ступеньке...

Comment: @Harry: Нет, ни первый, ни второй вариант смещать по `K` не надо - соответствия `K` и ответов они дают совершенно правильно. А вот для `K = 1` я бы сказал, что задача не определена вообще, поэтому не важно, что выдает в этом случае программа. (И `0` по этой причине - уместнее, чем `1`). Что касается второго способа - сам теоретический подход, разумеется, точен. Вопрос лишь в практической точности представления констант и точности промежуточных вычислений. Понятно, что чем точнее использованный плавающий тип - тем дольше будет "не врать" формула.

Comment: Вот ваша программа - https://ideone.com/gqLjIY. Вводим 1, получаем 0. Но на первую ступеньку можно попасть одним способом - шагнув не нее. Мы **не** стоим на первой ступеньке изначально. По-другому трактовать эту задачу, как мне кажется, невозможно... Кстати, исходя из того, что у ТС первые варианты проходят тестирование - то как раз все так и есть :) Ваши результаты отличаются от его результатов сдвигом на ступеньку. И задача, получается, определена. Просто вы решали не задачу ТС, а собственную - получение чисел трибоначчи...

Comment: Что до применения плавающей точки для целочисленных вычислений... А, впрочем, ладно. Считаете корректным давать ответ, не указывая ограничения его применимости - кто я такой, чтоб вам указывать?...

Comment: Что касается второго варианта - тут вы несете что-то непонятное о каком-то "применения плавающей точки для целочисленных вычислений" (O_o) (???). Никаких "целочисленных вычислений" тут нет и в помине. Закрытая форма для i-го члена последовательности Фибоначии и подобных последовательностей не то, что не целочисленна, она даже не рациональна (!). Я дал ссылочку - ознакомьтесь, там все подробно написано.

Comment: Что касается "ограничений применимости"... Вопросы ограничения точности плавающих типов ничем принципиально не отличаются от вопросов ограничений диапазона целочисленных типов. Здесь все прекрасно знают и существовании таких ограничений и традиции напоминать о них снова и снова в каждом ответе здесь нет (что, кстати, правильно). Это считается само собой разумеющимся. Если автор вопроса найдет в этом какие-то сюрпризы - будет лишь лишний повод ознакомиться с соответствующей темой.

Comment: Что касается соответствия между значением `K` и ответами в моих решениях - хорошо. Я исходил из того, что заяц изначально стоит на ступеньке номер `1`. То есть для `K=2` я даю ответ `1`. Согласно коду автора вопроса он исходит из того, что изначально заяц стоит на ступеньке номер `0`. Для такого случая мой код дает смещенные решения. Подправлю.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215103/holyblackcat за наводку

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
      long n;
      cin >> n;
      n++;
      long arr[n];
      arr[1]=1;
      arr[2]=2;
      arr[3]=4;
      for (int i=4;i<n;i++)
      {
        arr[i]=arr[i-1]+arr[i-2]+arr[i-3];
      }
      cout << arr[n-1];
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Если вы пишете так - `cin >> n; n++; long arr[n];` - то это уже не C++... Да и применение массива тут излишне - при каждом вычислении вам хватает только трех последних значений, все остальные можно не хранить.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (n<3) vr=n; else if (n==3) vr=4; else vr=(n-2)*3;
```

Comment: очевидно, уже для 4-х результат уже не верный... общая формула последовательности здесь будет экспоненциальной и иррациональной, так что для прямого вычисления она проблематична...

Comment: Интересно, что 3 человека считают линейную формулу верным ответом?

Comment: @Mikhailo: Последнее время на ruSO наблюдается "набег" каких-то загадочных трололо-минусователей и трололо-плюсователей. Такое было всегда, но сейчас прям какой-то всплеск. Понятно, конечно, что это не "органические" оценки ))